# Get hexdecimal number instead of the Active record

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I want to get a Station by `icao` using `station = Station.find_by(icao: "PADK")` but instead of getting something like this

```
#<Station 
          id: 1, aflag: "T", airport_id: nil, auto: "", 
          cd: "AK", country_code: "US", elev: "4", 
          iata: "ADK", icao: "PADK", latitude: 51.53, 
          longtitude: -176.39, mflag: "X", nexrad: "", 
          office: "", plotting: "7", station: "ADAK NAS", 
          synop: "70454", upair: "", created_at: "2016-02-18 20:19:58",
          updated_at: "2016-02-19 13:22:11">
```

i get `#<Station:0x00564249c81bf8>`. Where is the problem ?

It shows me the needed output in ruby console, but in .rb file it shows me a hexdecimal.

Comment: You're getting the active record object.  Are you then just outputting station?  i.e. `<%= station %>` because that will just call `.to_s` on the instance of station which would give you what you're getting.

Comment: It's just an .rb file

Comment: As @j-dexx is saying you need to specify an attribute (column) or you will get the entire object.

Comment: @Cloxure, what do you mean by "specifying" ? Am i not specyfing it using `.find_by` ?

Comment: `find_by` gets the instance if you want to output any of the attributes you need to call the getter method for that attribute.  e.g. `station.aflag`

Answer (score 1):

In console you get the result of `Station#inspect`, probably tuned by `awesome_print`. In web interface you get the result of `Station#to_s`, which outputs the same object in less verbose way.

In both cases it is the same object, having all it’s properties. Try:

```
station = Station.find_by(icao: "PADK")
if station
  puts "The station longtitude is #{station.longtitude}"
  puts station.inspect
else
  puts "There is no such station!"
end
```

Please note, that in case of many occurrences of stations with the param given, you’ll get an association array, rather than the particular result. In this case you might want to iterate through the response of `find_by`:

```
stations = Station.find_by(icao: "PADK")
stations.each do |station|
  puts station.whatever
end
```

Ruby console will still try to print out the whole array, and you’ll see it as the only `Station` instance it contains.

Comment: @mudaobwa, this is a better answer than mine, @VPaskar you should take a look at the `inspect` method if you want all the attributes.

Comment: It's interesting, when i'm trying to find by `longtitude` and `latitude` : `Station.find_by(latitde: "..", longtitude:" ..")`  i get the needed output, but when i'm trying to find it by `icao` i get this hexdecimal output, i'm wondering where's the problem

Comment: I can find the needed Station using any attribute excluding `icao`

Comment: OK, it seems that you have posted _the **incomplete** output_. Correct me, if I am wrong, but you get **`[#<Station:0x00564249c81bf8>]`** (note the square brackets.) That said, you have more than one stations for this `icao`, whatever it means. Go for `station.first` and/or loop `station.each` for this particular search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which attribute(s) you need from the Station model otherwise you will get the entire founded instance.

Example, lets suppose you need the "station" attribute within the Station model when the "icao"  is "PADK", then you should do something like this:

```
station = Station.find_by(icao: 'PADK').station
```

If you need more attributes just store them in different variables:

```
  padk_station = Station.find_by(icao: 'PADK')
  country_code = padk_station.country_code
  synop = padk_station.synop
```

And so on.

Comment: But if i need to get access to all the attributes of this instance using just this name `station` ?

Comment: `Station.find_by(icao: "PADK")` contains all the attributes, if you want to store them in variables or print them or display them in an html page, you will have to iterate on them,

`padk_station = Station.find_by(icao: "PADK")`
`country_code = padk_station.country_code`

Comment: I did as you say `station = Station.find_by(icao: "PADK").station` but got an error `scripts/get_stations.rb:133:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `station' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @mudasobwa's answer is better, give it a try.